# CoreData Fetched & return Empty array :o

Tags: ios, core-data

I have tried to re-write codes again and again. 
But still got  Empty Fetched Array.

Just try to follow some core DataBook.

making basic Model/Entity/ ,
Make a basic 1000a Items then saved to context.

But when try to fetch , always return an Empty array.
Fault also set = NO;

i wonder if something wrong with my code. 
i thought i have followed everything in the book. but still ...

```
//  AppDelegate.m
//  DudeRaw
//
//  Created by Zenjougahara on 11/20/15.
//  Copyright © 2015 Zenjougahara. All rights reserved.
//

#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "CoreDataHelper.h"

@interface AppDelegate ()

@property (strong,nonatomic) CoreDataHelper* CD;

@end

@implementation AppDelegate


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

   // [self.CD makePSConce];   /// create PSC on HDD only once
   // [self.CD insertDataToContext];
      [self.CD fetchdata];
    return YES;
}

- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
    /// SaveContext here !!
    [self.CD saveContext];
}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
    /// SaveContext here !!
    [self.CD saveContext];
}

-(CoreDataHelper*) CD{
    if(!_CD){
        _CD =  [[CoreDataHelper alloc]init];
        [_CD setupCoreData];
    }
    return _CD;
}


@end
```

---

```
//
//  CoreDataHelper.m
//  DudeRaw
//
//  Created by Zenjougahara on 11/20/15.
//  Copyright © 2015 Zenjougahara. All rights reserved.
//

#import "CoreDataHelper.h"
#import "Item.h"

@interface CoreDataHelper ()

@property (strong,nonatomic,readwrite) NSManagedObjectContext* con;
@property (strong,nonatomic,readwrite) NSManagedObjectModel* mo;
@property (strong,nonatomic,readwrite) NSPersistentStoreCoordinator* psc;
@property (strong,nonatomic,readwrite) NSPersistentStore* pstore;

@end

@implementation CoreDataHelper

#pragma mark FilePaths

-(NSURL*) originalDocumentURL{

    NSFileManager* fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    return [[fm  URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask]lastObject];
}

-(NSString*) folderName {
    return @"ProjectDxD";
}

-(NSString*) fileName{
    return @"MYCORED.sqlite";
}

-(NSURL*) withfolderURL {
    return [[self originalDocumentURL] URLByAppendingPathComponent:[self folderName]];
}

-(NSURL*) finalFileNameURL {
    NSURL* a  = [self withfolderURL];
    return [a URLByAppendingPathComponent: [self fileName]];
} // use this one

#pragma  mark PUBLIC METHODS

-(void)saveContext {
    NSError* err;
    if([_con hasChanges]){
        [_con save:&err];
    }
}
-(void) setupCoreData{
    _mo  =  [NSManagedObjectModel mergedModelFromBundles:nil];
    _psc =  [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc]initWithManagedObjectModel:_mo];
    _con =  [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc]initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];
    _con.persistentStoreCoordinator = _psc;

}  // setUP "not using LAZY init (cuz this is not thread- safe)


#pragma mark Method UsingOnce


-(void) makePSConce {
    NSError* err;
    NSFileManager* mng = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    if([mng fileExistsAtPath: [self finalFileNameURL].path]){
        return ;
    } else {
        [mng createDirectoryAtPath: [self withfolderURL].path
                    withIntermediateDirectories:YES
                    attributes:nil error:&err];
    }
    NSDictionary* op =  @{NSSQLitePragmasOption : @{@"journal_mode":@"DELETE"},
                          NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption :@YES,
                          NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption:@YES};

    _pstore = [_psc addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType
                             configuration:nil URL:[self finalFileNameURL]
                                   options:op error:&err];

}

-(void) insertDataToContext{
    NSError* err;
    for(int i = 1;i<=1000;i++){
        Item* a = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Item"
                                      inManagedObjectContext:_con];
        a.name =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"nameis + [%i]" , i];
        NSLog(@"name is %@",a.name);

        [_con save:&err];
    }
}

-(void) fetchdata{
    NSFetchRequest * req = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Item"];
    [req setReturnsObjectsAsFaults:NO];

    NSEntityDescription* des = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Item"
                                           inManagedObjectContext:_con];
    [req setEntity:des];
    NSSortDescriptor* sort = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"name"
                                                           ascending:YES];
    [req setSortDescriptors: [NSArray arrayWithObjects:sort, nil]];
    NSError* err;
    NSArray* a = [_con executeFetchRequest:req error:&err];

    NSLog(@"show me what fetched %@",a);

}

@end
```

this is what log telling me

1st RUN ) everything OK , inserted , fetched , and log appeared

Homebutton -> off application

[1stRun](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CqakV.png)

2nd RUN ) fetch only , empty Array :(
[2ndRUN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ri2rg.png)

Comment: When are you inserting, when fetching and what is the exact log output?

Comment: 1st) run successfully making .sqlite     [self.CD makePSConce];  [self.CD insertDataToContext];  
checked .sqlite with sqlitebrowser , 1000 items alrdy in

Comment: And you run it, change code, rerun in Xcode?

Comment: after the 1st run  i just  push home button in iOS Simulator (to make context saved)   then  mute the    [self.CD makePSConce]; [self.CD insertDataToContext];    and only run  Fetching codes         (yes rerun it)

Comment: Your `setupCoreData` method doesn't add a persistent store to the PSC.  You have to do this otherwise the PSC doesn't know which store to use.

Comment: added screenshots for more clarity !

Comment: Your second screenshot shows that no SQL calls were made: I think this is because (as per my comment above) the PSC doesn't have a store to use.

Comment: i just  [psc addPStoreWithtype : NSSQLIteStoreType]  and now everything work !!     .    Seem like i have big misunderstood about this method. (i thought this method adding more .sqlite file to HDD) (which I'm scared it may cause conflict)  so..... this Method really just making Pstore @ memory ?

Comment: This method "links" the PSC to the store - if the file already exists, it is used; if not, it is created.  There's no conflict.  Although it's named "add...", it is adding the store *to the PSC*, not (necessarily) *to the HDD*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check for whether there is an error returned by the fetch.  If there is this will help you know what is going wrong.  If no error and the array == nil then there are no objects that match the request and you can look at the code from there.

Also, in debugging CoreData this is one of my favorite tools:

`-com.apple.CoreData.SQLDebug 1` can be passed in as an argument and this will log exactly how long your fetch takes and how many objects are returned.  Also giving you much better insight into where your problem my be happening.

These should help you pinpoint exactly where your code is going wrong.